# Cases environment without the brace

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, cases

I want to vertically align one equation against two, similar to the `cases` environment but without the brace: e.g. similar environment to:

[image: withbraces]

There must be another solution to the alignment solution like [Case equation without curly brace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72903/case-equation-without-curly-brace) - I'd like to label it as a single equation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no need to create a special environment; a simple `array` environment will do the job.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
y = mx_{ij}\  
\begin{array}{l}
i = 1,2,\dots,n\\
j = 1,2,\dots,n
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

To make this a numbered `equation` environment, simply replace `\[` and `\]` with `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`, respectively.

Comment: Or `aligned` if `amsmath` is used; it's even simpler

Comment: @egreg - I guess it depends on what one considers to be "simpler"... By my reckoning, typing `\begin{array}{l}` and `\end{array}` requires 27 keystokes, whereas typing `\begin{aligned}`, `\begin{aligned}`, and the two `&` alignment characters requires 33 keystrokes...

Comment: [About keystrokes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142374/number-line-and-hatching/142377#comment322136_142377). :-)

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your code.
\begin{equation}
y=mx_{ij}
\quad
\!
\begin{aligned}
i &= 1,2,\ldots,n\\
j &= 1,2,\ldots,n
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can adjust the gap between the two lines with the optional argument to `\stackanchor`, currently set to 12pt.  I used a few `~~` for horizontal offset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
y = mx_{ij} ~~\ensurestackMath{\stackanchor[12pt]{i = 1,2,\ldots,n}
  {j = 1,2,\ldots,n}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]